# Is the Lie algebra of the Euclidean group $SE(3)$ semisimple?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

I know that the Euclidean group $SE(3)$ in the $3$ dimensions has the Lie algebra structure as the semidirect product of skew symmetric matrices and $\mathbb{R}^3$.

However, I cannot find a text saying anything about the simplicity or at least semisimplicity of this Lie algebra.

If it is semisimple, I can argue that it is not compact and so the Yang-Mills gauge lagrangian for $SE(3)$ is not positive-definite.

Could anyone help me with the simplicity of the Lie algebra of $SE(3)$?

Answer (score 2):

By $\mathbb R^3$ you mean an *abelian* $3$-dimensional Lie algebra which furthermore (as exhibited by the semidirect product) is an *ideal* of the Lie algebra in question. But the only nonzero ideals of semisimple Lie algebras are simple Lie algebras, and simple Lie algebras are not abelian.